# Rails method: :put route starts 'Get'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this in my `routes.rb`:

```
scope '/financial' do
  get '',                to: 'financial#index',    as: :financial
  get ':debnr',          to: 'financial#debnr',    as: :financial_debnr
  get ':debnr/pdf/:id',  to: 'financial#pdf',      as: :financial_pdf
  put ':debnr/pdf/:id',  to: 'financial#update',   as: :update_pdf
end
```

Then I have this in my `pdf.html.haml`:

```
= link_to 'Complete this pdf', 
           update_pdf_path(@debnr, @pdf), 
           method: :put, 
           data: { confirm: "You sure?"}
```

And in my `FinancialController`:

```
def update
  @pdf = Pdf.find(params[:id])
  @pdf.update_attribute(completed: true)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Unfortunately, when I click on the button, to complete the pdf, it's not working. It started the normal `get` action, like this:

```
Started GET "/financieel/20308/pdf/67" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-15 10:44:53 +0100
Processing by FinancieelController#pdf as HTML
```

It doesn't even say the message 'You sure?' and ignores the `method: :put` completely. Any thoughts?

#### Edit

html looks like this:

```
<a data-confirm="You sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/financial/123456/pdf/42">Complete this pdf</a>
```

#### Second Edit

I found it. I have been messing with the head, and i had accidentally commented out all the javascript files.

Sorry guys!

Comment: Can you please check if you have any errors in the JS console?
Also, can you please add the HTML of the generated link to your question?

Comment: Actually forget my answer that was a mistake while reading the source code. Different approach though: How does the html tag look in the rendered page?

Comment: I don't see any errors in my browser console. Is it possible that it only works on production? I am now on localhost:3000/...

Comment: HTML looks fine. The confirmation popup and request method are added with JS, so I guess there is an issue with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have rails-ujs (or jquery-ujs) added to the project?